# Cannot parse Json from HTTP request to Model class C#

Tags: asp.net, json

I have a HTTP Post request like below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("edit-request")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditRequet(Json request)
        {
            var response = await _claimProcessorService.ProcessClaim(request);
            return Accepted(response);
        }
```

The model class Json has:

```
    public class Json
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
```

The Request data can be both cases as shown below.

**Case I:**

```
{
    "Prop1": 1234,
    "Prop2": "test"                 
}
```

**Case II**

```
{
    "Prop1": "1234",
    "Prop2": "test"                 
}
```

**The Case I does not trigger the API whereas, the Case II is running smoothly. But I need both of the request to run**

Comment: What *does* Case I do?  Does it produce an error?  Trigger a different action method?  What happens if you create a second action method with a second model type which matches the request types?

Comment: Your action  will not be working with  post json request. Pls post a real action or  the code that calls the action

Answer (score 0):

Since `Json`'s `Prop1` is a string and in **Case I** you pass an integer this will not work.

You should probably make `Prop1` an integer and have the client always send this value as an integer instead of a string.

Alternatively you could create a second endpoint that accepts `Prop1` as a string.

Finally, you could create a custom `JsonConverter` that converts strings to numbers - if convertible.

However both the second and the third solution are really bad, I would go with the first and avoid these.